# When will Safe 1.4.1 support Arbitrum and Optimism testnets?

Tags: safe-core

We see that Safe 1.4.1 supports Arbitrum and Optimism mainnet, but not the testnets. We'd love to know when these testnets will be supported so we can do some testing for our product!

Answer (score 0):

you must be referring to Safe contracts not being deployed in these testnets? If yes, good news is you can deploy them and create a pull request to [this repo](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-smart-account#deployments) by following instructions in the readme file.

If you are referring to Safe Transaction Service supporting these networks, we do not plan to deploy our infrastructure on these for now, as we aim to focus our resources on the L2 mainnets.

Hope it helps! Best, Louis